# How to filter Dataframe Rows not containing any of a list of Substrings using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a python DataFrame with Spark 1.6. For example

```
DF= ("timestamp","canal", "name")
```

Example Data:

```
   [('1980-02-24'),('google.com/General'),('Alice')]
   [('1980-02-24'),('google.com/Dataset'),('bob')]
   [('1980-02-24'),('googleserach.com'),('Malik')]
   [('1980-02-24'),('googlesearch.com/AIPlateforme'),('AliceBob')]
   [('1980-02-24'),('yahooserach.com'),('Bob2')]
   [('1980-02-24'),('yahoosearch.com/AIPlateforme'),('Alice2')]

DF.count() = 6
```

I want take all the lines, that the `"canal"` `not contain` the `substring` `googleserach.com` and `yahoosearch`

I created a variable:

```
canal_2 = "googleserach.com,yahoosearch"
```

Then:

Solution 1:

```
result = DF.filter(~DF.canal.isin (canal_2)) ==> does not work
result.count() = 6
```

Solution 2:

```
if (canal2 not in DF.canal) ==> invalid syntax
```

How can I do a filtre on my DataFrame to take the lines that the "canal" not contain `googlesearch` and `yahoosearch` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`rlike` and `regex` will work.

```
regexNegativeLB= "^/(?!googlesearch|yahoosearch)$"
newDF= DF.filter(DF["canal"].rlike(regexNegativeLB))
```

https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html -- refer  Negative Lookahead

Answer (score 0):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([ 
 ('1980-02-24','google.com/General','Alice'),
 ('1980-02-24','google.com/Dataset','bob'),
 ('1980-02-24','googleserach.com','Malik'),
 ('1980-02-24','googlesearch.com/AIPlateforme','AliceBob'),
 ('1980-02-24','yahooserach.com','Bob2'),
 ('1980-02-24','yahoosearch.com/AIPlateforme','Alice2')
                 ], schema=("dt","canal","name"))

df.filter(~df.canal.like('%google.com%') & ~df.canal.like('%yahoosearch%')).show()
```

Also a possibility. pyspark does not have contains it appears.

Answer (score 0):

df.filter(~df["canal"].isin(canal_2)).collect()
Try this.

Comment: Substring is requested